# Failing Rspec tests in RT ch 9 for unknown reason

Tags: ruby, railstutorial.org

I am currently stuck between 9.13 and 9.2. I copied the spec and controller files exactly from that section but am still having trouble passing the Rspec tests. Getting this error--is it common? I haven't found it posted on here.

```
Failures:

1) User_pages edit with valid information Failure/Error: it { should have_title(new_name) } expected #has_title?("New Name") to return true, got false # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in '

2) User_pages edit with valid information Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') } expected #has_selector?("div.alert.alert-success") to return true, got false # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (4 levels) in '

3) User_pages edit with valid information Failure/Error: specify { expect(user.reload.name).to eq new_name }

   expected: "New Name"
        got: "John Smith"

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:50:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
4) User_pages edit with valid information Failure/Error: specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }

   expected: "new@example.com"
        got: "champion@aol.com"

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
Finished in 4.41 seconds 64 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47 # User_pages edit with valid information rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48 # User_pages edit with valid information rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:50 # User_pages edit with valid information rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:51 # User_pages edit with valid information
```

I have posted some of my code here: https://gist.github.com/ephunit/8293106

Let me know if you would like to see another file perhaps?

PS all my spec tests were Green before 9.13. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Interesting...when I do a runthrough on the webpage, click Settings in the Webapp to Update the Profile, and try to save a new password, I get the following error: 
The form contains 1 error. 
* Password confirmation can't be blank

Even though I tried to put in a new password.  Same error if I simply put in the original password.  This could be why I am failing.

Comment: is `champion@aol.com` what your factory created, meaning that it never got updated?

Comment: try running through the webapp manually , it appears that you are errorring out in update, check the logs, to see why it it isn't updating.

Comment: John Smith and Champion@aol.com are names I input myself on the site for "User 1"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "run through the webapp manually" or "erroring out in update".

Comment: it looks like your update action is failing.  Running through the webapp, I mean open it in a browser, and try to edit/update the account and see if it fails, and why it fails.

Comment: Interesting...when I go to Settings in the Webapp to Update the Profile, and try to save a new password, I get the following error: The form contains 1 error.
* Password confirmation can't be blank

Comment: You Should put all snippet of code here only, no one is interested in seeing your code at some where else. please edit and place all required piece of codes.

Comment: So the test is correct to fail, as your update action is failing (probably has to do with needing a conditional validation on checking your password fields.)

Comment: What file should I look to change, can you recommend me?  Thanks!

Comment: Would be in your user model need to only check for password confirmation cannot be be blank on create.

Comment: Have you resolved all of the issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spec_error

```
 1) User_pages edit with valid information Failure/Error: it { should have_title(new_name) } expected #has_title?("New Name") to return true, got false # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in '
```

this problem generally occurs when you do not put the **{title: sign-up}** like code at the top of your **view/static-pages** (for ex: **title: about** for about page). I don't know the exact piece of code but I was having the same problem and resolved with this solution.